# Member '<method>' cannot be accessed with an instance reference

Tags: c#, instance

The whole error text is:

> Member `'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(string, string, string, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions)'` cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Here's the code.  I removed "static" like in another post here, but it's still giving me the error.

I'd appreciate the assistance of all the experts on here - thanks!.

```
public string cleanText(string DirtyString, string Mappath)
{
    ArrayList BadWordList = new ArrayList();
    BadWordList = BadWordBuilder(BadWordList, Mappath);

    Regex r = default(Regex);
    string element = null;
    string output = null;

    foreach (string element_loopVariable in BadWordList)
    {
        element = element_loopVariable;
        //r = New Regex("\b" & element)
        DirtyString = r.Replace(DirtyString, "\\b" + element, "*****", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }

    return DirtyString;
}
```

Comment: Read: [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html), written by the guy who made this website.

Comment: What is `Regex r = default(Regex);` doing in your code?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is with the use of the method `Replace` not with the use of static in your declaration.  You need to use the typename `Regex` instead of the variable `r`

```
DirtyString = Regex.Replace(DirtyString, "\\b" + element, "*****", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The reason why is in C# you cannot access `static` methods through an instance of the type.  Here `Replace` is `static` hence it must be used through the type `Regex`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so first; `default(Regex)` will simply return null as `Regex` is a reference type.  So even if your code compiled, it would certainly crash with a `NullReferenceException` at this line as you never assign anything valid to `r`.

```
DirtyString = r.Replace(DirtyString, "\\b" + element, "*****", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Next, the compiler is telling you exactly what the problem is; `Replace` is a static method, not an instance method, so you need to use the typename as opposed to an instance variable.

```
DirtyString = Regex.Replace(...);
```